# Resources that explain or investigate artificial intelligence (AI) based approaches/strategies to the game of Mahjong

Tags: artificial-intelligence, mahjong

While Mahjong (the actual game, not Mahjong solitare) is fairly simple in terms of basic rules and gameplay, setting objectives for the AI to transition to aim for certain end game goals seems fairly complex.

Is anyone aware of any papers, research, or other materials related to this topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this could be what you are looking for:

> A Mah Jong-Playing Program
>
> A masters  thesis written at the Department of  Information Technology
>
> by Daniel Hellsson
>
> with supervisors Jan Eric  Larsson and Bengt Öhman
>
> 1 September, 2000

http://www.it.lth.se/janeric/mastersprojects/past/hellsson/mother.pdf

Comment: broken link? can you post the PDF somewhere else?

Comment: For those looking for it [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20090530104745/http://www.it.lth.se/janeric/mastersprojects/past/hellsson/mother.pdf) has it.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at **AI Mahjong** by Wan Jing Loh, December 11th 2009 ([PDF](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs229/proj2009/Loh.pdf)).

> In this project, I attempted to
>   develop a viable AI Mahjong player, by
>   building a hand evaluator that is able
>   to accurately calculate how many tiles
>   from victory the player is.